# what do em0, em1, em2 and em3 interfaces refer to on Juniper routers

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, management

Can someone explain what these interfaces are for? I know em0 is used as a management interface on the router to connect via ssh but why are the other two there? I have also noticed, sometimes they have a private address configured by themselves.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> em0 and em1 are the internal interfaces on the Routing Engine (RE).

https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB33394&cat=MX960_1&actp=LIST&showDraft=false